# Ideal table package

Tags: tables

I tried a lot of table packages but none of them does everything I need.

I need fixed width of the table, some padding in the cells, it should be able to do multicolumn and centering text vertically and horizontally. It should also be able to break lines manually with not affecting vertical align of other cells.

Does anything like this exists? Thank you!

---

I would like to have this table:

[image: Table I would like to have]

And I have for example this code which is pretty difficult and not everything I need is there:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\tabulinesep=2.2mm
   \begin{tabu} to 16cm {|X[2,c]|X[2,c]|}
   \hline
   \multicolumn2{|c|}{\textbf{Reklama}} \\ \tabucline 
      \firsthline 
 \underline{\textbf{Malířství Praha}} & \\
 Maluješ, malujeme, malujete & \\
 Objednávejte nyní & Text reklamy je nejasný a matoucí. \\
 \textit{malirstvi-praha.cz}\\
\hline
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

which looks like this:

[image: LaTeX code]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you checked out the `tabularx` package?

Comment: Hi, thank you. Yes, I tried tabular, tabularx, tabu, TAB and other I don't remember. Unfortunately every of them is not able to do everything I need.

Comment: Please make your question more specific, adding a concrete table you have tried to produce and the code you have tried to make it work.

Comment: you can do all of the things you mention with varying degrees of difficulty just using a standard tabular and no packages. The packages make some things easier (hopefully). As it stands your question is far too broad to be answered, you need to narrow down on a specific problem, preferably with a complete small example that does not produce the result you expect.

Comment: And unfortunately I'm not such good in latex so most of the time I just copy the codes and rewrite some parts of it.

Comment: As you see, code in comments doesn't really work, you can edit your question to add it in a code section `{}` button in the editor so line breaks work, but please post a full document `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` and say what output you wanted

Answer (score 2):

A version with `tabularx` and vertically centered cells via column specifier `m` of package `array`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand*{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn2{|c|}{\textbf{Reklama}} \\
  \hline
   \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
     \underline{\textbf{Malířství Praha}}\\
     Maluješ, malujeme, malujete\\
     Objednávejte nyní
     \textit{malirstvi-praha.cz}\\
    \end{tabular}
  & Text reklamy je nejasný a matoucí. \tabularnewline
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Version with larger vertical spaces

A larger `\arraystretch` only works fine with regular lines. It does not have an effect, if the table cell is too larger in height or depth.
Adding vertical spaces the traditional way has problems with vertical rules.

The following example adds them via invisible rules:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand*{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}

\newcommand*{\tabvspace}{2ex}

\newcommand*{\tabtopspace}[1]{%
  \sbox0{#1}%
  \ht0=\dimexpr\ht0 + \tabvspace\relax
  \rule{0pt}{\ht0}%
  \ignorespaces#1%
}
\newcommand*{\tabbottomspace}[1]{%
  \sbox0{#1}%
  \dp0=\dimexpr\dp0 + \tabvspace\relax
  \rule[-\dp0]{0pt}{0pt}%
  \ignorespaces#1%
}
\newcommand*{\tabbothspaces}[1]{%
  \sbox0{#1}%
  \ht0=\dimexpr\ht0 + \tabvspace\relax
  \dp0=\dimexpr\dp0 + \tabvspace\relax
  \rule[-\dp0]{0pt}{\dimexpr\ht0 + \dp0\relax}%
  \ignorespaces#1%
}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn2{|c|}{\tabbothspaces{\textbf{Reklama}}} \\
  \hline
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}} 
    \tabtopspace{\underline{\textbf{Malířství Praha}}}\\
    Maluješ, malujeme, malujete\\
    Objednávejte nyní 
    \tabbottomspace{\textit{malirstvi-praha.cz}}\\
  \end{tabular}
  & Text reklamy je nejasný a matoucí. \tabularnewline
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with larger vertical spaces]

Comment: Thank you! But as I said I need some vertical padding same up and down.

Comment: @Daniel See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

With small correction of your columns definition and merging cells you can obtain:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\tabulinesep =_4mm^4mm
\begin{tabu} to 16cm {|X[m]|X[m]|}
   \hline
\multicolumn2{|c|}{\textbf{Reklama}} \tabularnewline
    \tabucline
\textbf{\underline{\bfseries Malířství Praha}}

Maluješ, malujeme, malujete         

Objednávejte nyní                   

\textit{malirstvi-praha.cz} &   Text reklamy je nejasný a matoucí. 
    \tabularnewline
    \hline
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

*Notice:*

- Empty lines in table setting are intentional
- I had problem with underlined text in `tabu` environment, works only this strange construction `\textbf{\underline{\bfseries Malířství Praha}`. Maybe some problem with my fonts installation.